# Get date in golang like "2018-07-13"

Tags: go

how to get date in golang like this formate "2018-07-13"

main.go file

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(time.Now())
}
```

> $ go run main.go

otuput:

> 2018-07-13 21:25:16.796379489 +0500 +05 m=+0.000120455

how to write function to return date in string like this formate "2018-07-13"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fmt.Println(time.Now().Format("2006-01-02"))`

https://play.golang.org/p/AOrLRNkOxP_b

[reference](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Format)